# Capturing geolocations - Phonegap

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I want to create a Phonegap application which will save the current geolocation on network drop.
For example as soon as my network or data connectivity goes off I want to capture geolocation at particular time.
I don't know if it's completely possible but will appreciate if someone can direct & guide me to appropriate path. Blog links, guidance will definitely help.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you had previous experience with Phonegap?

Comment: Yes a bit i created bar code scanner app with certain modifications as per my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for geolocation, setting in your config.xml and :

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

is easy to use it and to detect when your app goes offline, you can use this  [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information).

So the file would be something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);    
}

function onSuccess(){
    alert('position detected'); 
}

function onError(){
    alert('ERROR Detecting your current position'); 
}
```